# Apply function to column of pandas dataframe in chunks (every few rows), interspersed with time.sleep()

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe, one for user IDs and another for information I will populate, like this:

```
user_id | user_INFO
--------------------
id1     |
id2     |
id3     |

       etc.
```

I have a function that makes API calls to get user info (which will be dicts) based on the user_id, and I'd like the info returned from this function to populate the user_INFO column. So my code looks like:

```
df['user_INFO']=df['user_id'].apply(lambda x:get_user_INFO(x))
```

The problem is that I run into API limits every 15 minutes- moreover, my options for error handling are limited because when I hit the limit, an empty dictionary is returned (instead of throwing an error). I also can't have the script pause for 15 min. every time I get an empty dictionary, because an empty dictionary is supposed to be returned for certain users (when their profiles are private, for example).

I do know that I can get around 178 rows of user_INFO data before I hit the API rate limit. So I'm thinking of writing a script that applies the function to 178 rows, then waits 15 min., then repeats for the next 178 rows, etc. until I reach the end of the dataframe. Does this seem like the best way to solve this? If so, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Or if you have any other ways of approaching this problem, I'd be open to suggestions.